# Trying to make fire in a glass cube

Tags: glass, fire

I'm trying to make a transparent cube or glass cube with fire in the middle of it so you can see it in the cube.  I've tried different ways to make the cube transparent but I don't see the flames but in the render, the emitter is visible but no flames.

Does someone knows what to do? :)

Thank you for your comments! I've tried to make it with a glass shader and both transparent and translucent shaders.  In the render, i can see the emitter and the glass cube as I like it. But I don't see any flames in the cube. They just don't show  up. I dont have any pictures now.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! As of now there's too little information to answer your question. Could you please provide some more? Which ways of making the cube transparent did you already try? How did you make the fire? Do you see the fire without the cube? Please click "edit" underneath your question and add this information, images do not hurt either! We are here to help you, it's just difficult when we don't really know what the problem is.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information as well as images that might help us understand your scene and settings. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))

Comment: Most important question, what Blender version? I see that there is some bug right now (today 2.8 build) with smoke/fire rendering.

Comment: Hi cgslav. Im using the 2.79 i think :)